# How can you discover a password shared via LastPass?

Tags: lastpass

I'm trying to set up a personal accountant with access to some of my financial accounts. I would like to use LastPass sharing to give them access to the accounts without giving them access to a password that could be used by third parties. However, according to what appears to be a LP staff comment, the recipient of the shared password could just inspect the element in his browser and discover the original password. Can this possibly be the way it actually works??? If so, what's the point?

[image: https://blog.lastpass.com/2016/01/tips-for-securely-sharing-passwords.html/]

Comment: just try it yourself, share a password to another browser, let lastpass put in the password -> right click and inspect element and change the <input type="password" ...... > to <input type="text" .......>. inb4 of course you'll see the password

Answer (score 1):

You can't. End of discussion.

For them to log in, they **have** to know the password. If this is not acceptable to you, you will have to work out a solution with your provider where two separate accounts can get access to the same data. In my country, this is a rather common feature for banks.

Note that sharing your password will probably be in breach of any contract you have with the banks, which may severely limit their liability.

Comment: The last paragraph is strongly geographically influenced - in parts of the EU, that's no longer allowed as part of banking terms and conditions, where the sharing is with a regulated provider (which you'd hope an accountant was) - see https://www.fca.org.uk/consumers/account-information-and-payment-initiation-services for the details on the rules in the UK, for one.

Comment: @Matthew "Your banking terms and conditions should not prevent you from sharing your credentials with regulated AIS or PIS providers" - this does probably not include sharing passwords with friends or relatives...

Comment: @vidario Yeah, I specifically included the bit about "regulated provider" since the original question was about an accountant. Doesn't apply to family!